# Mysql query use regular expression and underscore

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to write a mysql query to select all tables which start with an underscore followed by only numbers.

I have tried a few things, non of which work. The table names are all an underscore with 6 digits (_123456)after it:

```
SELECT Table_Name FROM information_schema.Tables WHERE Table_Name REGEXP '_^[0-9]'

SELECT Table_Name FROM information_schema.Tables WHERE Table_Name REGEXP '\_^[0-9]'
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why is `^` in the middle of your regular expression?

Comment: For some reason I thought that meant all characters after it are 0-9. I've now realised it means the start of a line

Comment: You got it. If you're ever struggling with regular expressions, which is honestly how it goes until you've really mastered them, don't be afraid to use a [testing tool](https://regex101.com) to explain what you're doing and verify it works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close except for the start anchor and the number of digits to check.

This should work.

```
Table_Name REGEXP '^_[0-9]{6}$'
```

Comment: A `_` is not a special symbol in regular expressions, it does not have to be escaped.